# How would I get it to fade to another view when rotated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know how to get the view to fade in, but how do I see when they've rotated the screen left or right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005389/detecting-rotation-to-landscape-manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-load views, change views, basically do anything you want in the shouldAutoRotate method of your UIViewController:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You can manipulate anything you like here.  I have a UIWebView that loads a page optimized for portrait or landscape depending on what orientation this method tells me is coming.

As for the fade, you can use UIViewAnimations

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
play with the alpha (1 is full display; 0 is total fade)
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the view hierarchy on interface rotation are best made in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. The view controller will call this method from inside the animation block it creates for the rotation animation.