# Issue with orientations of 2 UIViewcontrollers in navigation controller application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a tabbar application. And the item of first tab is Navigation Controller.
Navigation controller has 4 items in his stack.
I want to provide rotation. But in tabbar application it's the problem, that's why I created my own tabbarcontroller and override the method:

```
@interface RotatingTabBarController : UITabBarController

@end

@implementation RotatingTabBarController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
        BOOL f = [[(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController visibleViewController] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
        return f;
    } else {
        BOOL f = [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
        return f;
    }
}

@end
```

After that if I provide in proper UIInterfaceOrientation support, my controllers will support autorotation. But without my custom RotatingTabBarController it's seems impossible

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

The problem is:
When I push FirstViewController  in navigation controller in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation of this viewcontroller I provide only portrait orientation, 
but when I push SecondViewController (I provide there both portrait and landscape orientation), if current interface orientation  of SecondViewController is landscape and I press back button (SecondViewController pop from stack and FirstViewController appears), the orientation of FirstViewController is landscape. But in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method I provide only portrait orientation for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used modal windows and hide back button in Landscape orientation. It solved the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I recommended.

You have possibility to support different orientation for a view using modal view controller, which is not on stack of a navigation controller.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should not subclass a UITabbarController class.

> The UITabBarController class implements a specialized view controller that manages a radio-style selection interface. This class is not intended for subclassing.

From [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you view controllers override

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

method, it should be fine.

I think it is not a good idea to support for some views landscape orientation and for some not in a app.

You have already the reason discovered, what if users presses back button while in landscape mode?

What should be done here, rotate to portait while the device has landscape orientation?

If you want to do so, there is no easy way to force the device to change the orientation. You have to handle the orientations of views your self using transformations.

You have possibility to support different orientation for a view using model view controller, which is not on stack of a navigation controller.

Comment: 1) The First view controller supports only Portrait orientation. Why it appears in landscape orientation after I press back from SecondViewController?
2) First view controller is a table view, second view controller is picture gallery, that's why I need SecondView controller to support both orientations, and FirstViewController to support only portrait orientation.
3) about "What should be done here, rotate to portait while the device has landscape orientation", I want FirstViewController to appear in portrait orientation while device is in landscape orientation.

Comment: 1) The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method get called only after device orientation changes, and not while changing the tab. So you select you second tab and ios call the method and get YES, so it rotates. When you change the first tab it just uses the last orientation. And you can not force it to rotate, unless you use transformations and handle all rotation events. 2) If you use for some reason, that just one controller supports landscape orientation then you have the possibility to present it as model view controller and not a controller of a tabbar controller.

Comment: 3) So you want to force a rotation while switching tabs. Like already said there is no easy way to do that. If you really want to do that you need to rotate the view your self. Note: I would think about it before doing it. As a user when I start your app and on first tab it is just portrait orientation supported then why should I try for other tabs? So you will have many user who do not know about your landscape support for second tab, unless you put some text or image about it. Even if you do that, I think it is not that good when I have to rotate my phone many times while I am using your app

Comment: Thanks, good answer. But I don't want to force a rotation while switching tabs. I want to do it, when I use my navigation controller and press back button.
But I understand the basic idea. I have the last question:
I rotated view with self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
but how to rotate navigationController and status bar without causing any problems?

Comment: You need to rotate view of your navigation controller not the view of your controller. For status bar [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: animated:] method should help

Comment: if I use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:Portrait animated:], the view is OK, it looks proper, but device orientation is still landscape, and when I rotate the device to Portrait orientation, it's still in landscape orientation and I can't change it even in other view controllers.
The controller, where I make all Affine transforms has the method - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);}

Comment: If you rotate the view your self then you are responsible to rotate it back. You can register for device orientation changes to notification center and get a notification. In that notification method you can handle your rotations. The exact notification methods can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005389/detecting-rotation-to-landscape-manually

Comment: I read the info from your link, but they don't answer how they manage status bar. I faced the problem: a) when in landscape mode I set the status bar orientation as Portrait, the orientation of view controllers is sill landscape b) then , when I rotate device to Portrait,I get the notification about that and set status bar orientation to Portrait one more time, but never the less the device orientation is still landscape.

Comment: How can I rotate status bar to portrait without problems, that I listed above? What do you mean "responsible to rotate it back", do I need to set the status bar orientation to Portrait one more time? I think , that the problem is when the device in landscape mode and I set the status bar orientation to Portrait, the view controller orientation will not change to portrait even if I rotate it to portrait (because it thinks, that it's already in portrait because of status bar).