# View stuck in portrait in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view in a view controller.

When I rotate the device, the view controller rotates, but the view seems to be stuck in portrait mode.

Check the image from the simulator.

[image: from the simulator]

Comment: Please provide us with your code and nib/storyboard screenshots with your  autolayout configuration for that view (controller).

Comment: here is the storyboard with the view selected http://imgur.com/rbEH26s and here is the code http://pastie.org/10743726

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange the view for the landscape.

You can do this by code, changing the elements position [when detect a rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005389/detecting-rotation-to-landscape-manually), or, the more usual way, using **auto-layout**, [here you have](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) a more detailed guide to how to do it.

Another way of solving, is not enabling rotation, you can set in the General options of the project, like this a portrait only mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the view to  be independent from the orientation change, and resize itself, I would suggest looking into Xcode's [Auto-Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

If you'd like to disallow orientation changes for your entire application (your view will rotate with the phone), see @UlyssesR 's answer.

Comment: reading about auto-layout now.  I only want this one view to be forced into landscape mode, the rest of the views can rotate

Comment: If you only want certain views to rotate on a device orientation change, consider rotating the view either using Size Classes, or doing it programmatically using [UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification)